# Javascript doesn't update DOM until user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, signalr

I'm adding a chat feature to my site using angularJS and signalR. It is very barebones right now...My angular controller maintains an array of chat logs, and
prints them out with:

```
         <div ng-repeat="log in vm.logs">{{log.sender}}: {{log.msg}}</div>
```

All the wiring works, and I have verified via console.log() that messages are being received instantly. However, it seems the DOM is not updated until I interact with the page (such as hovering over another component that has an angular action attached to it). I'm not sure if it's an issue  with angular or just javascript. Any ideas?

I've seen this on sites like Facebook, and I thought it was by design but it looks like it's a browser/javascript thing.

Comment: how do you add element to your array in your controller?

You have write vm.logs in your code above are you sure it's the good controller name ?

Comment: Did you call `$scope.$apply()` on the callback from signalR?

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout and wrap your vm.logs scope array with a function. $timeout automatically calls the angulars digest cycle and your dom should start getting updated.

Comment: Yep, already using $timeout. Sorry, should have mentioned it.